# How to specify the path to a Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm new to Rust and I want to build and run my project. I use something like:

```
cd %project_path%
cargo run
```

I want to be able to write `cargo run -path %project_path%` in a single line because I want to create a build script that doesn't allow changing the working directory. It seems that cargo doesn't have any `-path` or `-target` keys, which would define target directory, and I always get the message

> could not find `Cargo.toml` in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` or any parent
>   directory

Comment: Maybe you want the `--manifest-path` option? (The `--help` argument will print the arguments and descriptions of them.)

Comment: I want to be able to compile and run a project placed not in current working directory, but in path which I specify

Comment: In *nix shell terminology, you could use `(cd $project_path; cargo run)`: start a new subshell, in which you change directory and then execute the desired task. For Windows I think that’d be something vaguely along the lines of `cmd -c "cd %project_path%; cargo run"`.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy, did you try the `--manifest-path` option?

Comment: @huon i was thinking that it's for metadata info and so on, but it has needed behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `--manifest-path path/to/Cargo.toml` option to almost all `cargo` subcommands allows pointing it to a specific `Cargo.toml` file to use, overriding the default of searching the current directory and its parents for a file called `Cargo.toml` (this file is the "manifest").

Incidentally, unix-y commands usually take a `-h` or `--help` argument which prints information about their command line options, `cargo` and `rustc` are no exception. E.g.

```
$ cargo run --help
Run the main binary of the local package (src/main.rs)

Usage:
    cargo run [options] [--] [<args>...]

Options:
    -h, --help              Print this message
    --bin NAME              Name of the bin target to run
    --example NAME          Name of the example target to run
    -j N, --jobs N          The number of jobs to run in parallel
    --release               Build artifacts in release mode, with optimizations
    --features FEATURES     Space-separated list of features to also build
    --no-default-features   Do not build the `default` feature
    --target TRIPLE         Build for the target triple
    --manifest-path PATH    Path to the manifest to execute
    -v, --verbose           Use verbose output
    -q, --quiet             No output printed to stdout
    --color WHEN            Coloring: auto, always, never

If neither `--bin` nor `--example` are given, then if the project only has one
bin target it will be run. Otherwise `--bin` specifies the bin target to run,
and `--example` specifies the example target to run. At most one of `--bin` or
`--example` can be provided.

All of the trailing arguments are passed to the binary to run. If you're passing
arguments to both Cargo and the binary, the ones after `--` go to the binary,
```

Comment: I know what `-h` command does but I didn't expect that `manifest to execute` is `cargo.toml`. Just a misunderstanding. I was thinking it's an additional metadata file (like application manifest in `.Net`), this is why I didn't use this key. Thanks for an answer.

Comment: The `--manifest-path` option worked only when the given file was explicitly named `Cargo.toml` for me. In my use case, I want to have two manifest files, one for Production and one for development environment. I have a makefile where I want to specify which manifest file to use based on the target. Has anyone done that?